# Get type of parameter with Reflection

Tags: php, reflection

I am using the following code to get the methods from a class:

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass ( $className );
$methods = $reflector->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
print_r ( $methods[0] );
```

Then all i get from it is the `name` of the property. But I am also interested in the property type. How can i get that info?

Comment: Are you trying to get the methods's return value type? This is not possible in the current version of reflection

Comment: @onetrickpony no the type of the methods params. Like `function foo (array $arr);` I want to know what type `$arr` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by doing:

```
$params = $methods[0]->getParameters();
$params[0]->getClass()->name;
```

You can only use `getClass()->name` if that param is strong typed.

Comment: getClass is deprecated now, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the list of parameters
$params = $methods[0]->getParameters();

foreach($params as $param){

  if($param->isArray()){
    // array...

  }else{
    // something else...    

    try{
      $paramClass = $param->getClass();

      if($paramClass !== null){
        // it's a required class ($paramClass->name)
        // note that the class must be loaded at this point
      }

    }catch(\Exception $e){

    }

  }

}
```

These are the only parameter hints you can detect with reflection.